# Trying to implement polymorphism when one type needs an extra property

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, polymorphism

I have two interfaces:

```
interface IDynamicControl
{
    string Id { get; set; }
    string Label { get; set; }
    string Value { get; set; }
}

interface IDynamicList : IDynamicControl
{
    IList ListItems { get; set; }
}
```

I have a `ControlResolver` class that returns `IDynamicControl` - for my purposes I have wrapper classes for ASP.NET TextBoxes, CheckBoxes and DropDownLists which implement IDynamicControl (DropDown implements IDynamicList).  The gist is I can give the resolver the name of a control, for example "Textbox", and it will give me back an IDynamicControl that is a modified ASP.NET Textbox.

This works perfect BUT the issue is the DropDownList.  Maybe I'm having a brain fart but the problem I'm running into is that when the control is a dropdown, I'm having to do an explicit cast to IDynamicList (since the resolver returns IDynamicControl) so I can add the items to it for display.  This normally wouldn't be an issue but the purpose of the dynamic control is that I can store the field type externally and read it in, so I would have to do something ugly like:

```
string controlType = SomeService.GetControlType();
if (controlType == "dropdown")
{
    var control = (IDynamicList)ControlResolver.ResolveControl(controlType);
    // set up list items
}
else
{
    var control = ControlResolver.ResolveControl(controlType);
    // stuff with normal controls
}
```

but this seems fairly ugly.  I could include the ListItems property in the base and just throw NotImplemented in the classes that don't use it, but that violates ISP and is even smellier than the if statement.  In short I'd like to have my resolver return one type of control so I don't need to have different Resolve() methods, but in the consuming code there is extra work I have to do if, and only if, the control is a dropdown.

Unless I'm mistaken or I've forgotten something basic, is there a better solution for doing this or should I just use the if statement?  I can't use a base class since all of my "Dynamic" classes inherit from the base ASP.NET UI classes.

Comment: why don't you use IList<IDynamicControl> ListItems ?

Comment: Because the DynamicList isn't a list of controls, it mimics the `Items` collection of a dropdown list.  Since the type of control created is variable, if it's a dropdown I'll need to do extra processing to get the list items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest way to refactor your original code to something cleaner would be the following:

```
        var control = ControlResolver.ResolveControl(controlType);

        // ... do common logic for all controls

        var list = control as IDynamicList;
        if (list != null)
        {
            // .. do additional logic for list controls
        }
```

Your code that calls `ControlResolver.ResolveControl` shouldn't really have to know any special rules for "dropdown" controls.  All it really needs to know is whether or not the resolved control implements the `IDynamicList` interface.

Granted, you still have to have some conditional logic, but at least the conditions are based on well-known interfaces that your code is already aware of instead of underlying implementation details.

Of course, there are other approaches that you can take to go further down the path of abstraction, but this seems like a small change that can be made without impacting any other code.

Answer (score 2):

A single method can't return different types unless it is non-generic. In your case you can't pass a generic type argument so you have to apply some kind of explicit cast anyway. Moreover, since you have different setup logic you'll have to apply some conditional checks as well.

One thing you can get rid of is the conditional `if` checks (just imagine how many `if's` yu need in case of 10 types of control), you can use  `IDictionary` as cache of initialize functions so code would be much clean:

```
IDictionary<string, Func<IDynamicControl>> setupWorkerProvider
```

and then resolve the  appropriate setup function in single line:

```cs
// once setup setup provider
setupWorkerProvider.Add("dropdown", (dynamicControl) => { /*setup logic here*/ });
setupWorkerProvider.Add("button", (dynamicControl) => { /*setup logic here*/ });

// resolve initializer
var setupWorker = setupWorkerProvider[controlType];

// initialize control
setupWorker(control);
```

Comment: Agreed, there really is not much that can be done when he needs more than the base type interface in the case of a drop down.

Answer (score 0):

This is as it should be. Your ResolveControl method has provided a contractual guarantee that it will return an IDynamicControl. It does not guarantee that it will return anything more specific than that.

Imagine if you had the following code:

```
public Object foo(int x) {
    if (x%2 == 0) {
        return new String("Hello");
    } else {
        return new Integer(1);
    }
}
```

Would you expect callers to have all of the String methods and all of the Integer methods available?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that since you *know* you want a IDynamicList you have a resolver method (ListControlResolver?) that returns one. Maybe it simply calls your existing resolver and casts it before returning, but you as the caller don't care about that. Heck, this could be good for later down the road when you want to manage other list-y controls.